# PRAW raising RequestException when I try to run simple bot

Tags: python, exception, bots, reddit, praw

I'm trying to write a redditbot; I decided to start with a simple one, to make sure I was doing things properly, and I got a RequestException.

my code (bot.py):

```
import praw

for s in praw.Reddit('bot1').subreddit("learnpython").hot(limit=5):
    print s.title
```

my praw.ini file:

```
# The URL prefix for OAuth-related requests.
oauth_url=https://oauth.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for regular requests.
reddit_url=https://www.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for short URLs.
short_url=https://redd.it

[bot1]
client_id=HIDDEN
client_secret=HIDDEN
password=HIDDEN
username=HIDDEN
user_agent=ILovePythonBot0.1
```

(where HIDDEN replaces the actual id, secret, password and username.)

my Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    for s in praw.Reddit('bot1').subreddit("learnpython").hot(limit=5):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 79, in next
    return self.__next__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 52, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 62, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 322, in get
    data = self.request('GET', path, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 406, in request
    params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 131, in request
    params=params,  url=url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 70, in _request_with_retries
    params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prawcore/rate_limit.py", line 28, in call
    response = request_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prawcore/requestor.py", line 48, in request
    raise RequestException(exc, args, kwargs)
prawcore.exceptions.RequestException: error with request request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  PS, I am using Python 2.7., on Ubuntu 14.04.  Please ask me for any other information you may need.

Comment: This is rather strange. What version of praw, prawcore, and requests do you have: Replace PACKAGE with the name of each to get the version: `python -c 'from PACKAGE import __version__; print(__version__)'` My hunch is that you have an older version of requests that doesn't support that parameter. However, that shouldn't be possible if you use pip to install praw. How did you install praw?

Comment: @bboe I am using:
praw 4.1.0
prawcore 0.5.0
requests 2.2.1

I installed praw with pip.

Comment: That's really interesting as prawcore depends on `requests >= 2.9.1` so pip _shouldn't_ have successfully installed PRAW with that version. Try `pip install -U praw` and see if it changes the requests version at all.

Comment: I tried `pip install -U praw`, (as well as the fix suggested by @Bantu below), did not update my requests version.

Answer (score 0):

The way i see it, it seems you have a problem with your request to Reddit API. Maybe try changing the user-agent in your in-file configuration. According to [PRAW basic configuration Options](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/options.html#basic-configuration-options) the user-agent should follow a format `<platform>:<app ID>:<version string> (by /u/<reddit username>)` . Try that see what happens.

Comment: I tried this, it had no effect.  I got the same error et al.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso the JSON parameter was not introduced in requests versions < 2.4.2 and your version of request is 2.2.1. Try updating it using pip  `pip install requests` . If that does not work then you must have an older requests library conflicting with the newer one.

Comment: I tried `pip install requests`, (as well as the fix suggested by @bboe above), did not update my requests version.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso well what does it say? what's the error?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso You should use virtualenv if you are not using one already. It will basically allow you to start from a clean state and separate your project from other libraries in your system. 1. `pip install virtualenv` 2. `cd my_project_dir`  3. `virtualenv prawenv` 4. `source prawenv/bin/activate`. Then you can install all latest version of dependencies that your project needs 5. `pip install requests`

Comment: when I try to update requests, there are no errors.  It seemed to work properly, but then when I check the version, it's the same.  I can post everything printed out if that would help. Alright, I will try to use a virtualenv tonight, see how that goes, and get back to you.